# Call java library in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I need to add a java class library to Matlab. If I add the path to the static java class path in Matlab, Matlab cannot access it. But if I use javaaddpath() from the command-line and add the java library to the dynamic java class path, then Matlab can access it. What is the possible reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted Matlab?
It only loads the content of the static path on starting.
BTW. Use the dynamic path. Its a cleaner solution.